# Create Snow Flakes in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created snow flakes in jquery.Creating and removing a div may cause the script to unresponsive. Right now i tried jquery with `animate()` 
I want to generate the flakes with 20 at a same time of page load. I am not sure when i tried this method may cause this unresponsive mean (Browser has get too slow)

**Here is the New jquery Code**

```
function jquerysnow() {

    snowCount = 20;
       var snow = $('<div class="snow"></div>');
        $('#snowflakes').prepend(snow);
        snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#snowflakes').width());
        snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 20);

        snow.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
    snow.html('*');
        snow.animate({
            top: "500px",
            opacity : "0",

        }, 2000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            jquerysnow();
        });



}
jquerysnow();
```

See this here a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/v7LWx/6/)**

Now it showing one flake at a time once the flakes disappear itself it generate next.
How can i generate multiple flakes without unresponsive script.

Comment: One little thing, add `overflow: hidden` to the body. Pretty nice :)

Comment: Add jquerysnow(); twice or thrice for the multiple snow flakes. (at script end)

Comment: There may be more ways, but i knw only this one :)

Comment: You can generate the elements and then do the animation with CSS (including a sine-wave floating back-and-forth effect) if you only need to support the latest browsers.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: My Apologies @wumm I edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out, pretty simple i just added a function that triggers jquerysnow() and then calls itself again wit random time

updated code now it will just create 20 snow flakes

```
snowCount = 0;
function snowFlakes(){
    console.log(snowCount);
    if(snowCount > 20){

        return false
    }else{
    var randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 2);
    setTimeout(function(){
        snowCount = snowCount +1;
        jquerysnow();
       snowFlakes();
    },randomTime);
    }
}
function jquerysnow() {


       var snow = $('<div class="snow"></div>');
        $('#snowflakes').prepend(snow);
        snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#snowflakes').width());
        snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 20);

        snow.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
    snow.html('*');
        snow.animate({
            top: "500px",
            opacity : "0",

        }, 2000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            //jquerysnow();
        });



}

snowFlakes()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7LWx/390/

Answer (score 1):

I just finished writing an article on the subject and I thought I'd share.

It's not very jQuery-heavy though, mostly pure good old javascript. But it produces a pretty decent snow-falling effect.

So, for anyone interested, [here it goes!](http://www.geomagas.gr/index.php/snowflakes-in-javascript/)