# Create Random Falling Object in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to make the div fall from top to bottom. 
Here is the code that i tried but it doesn't satisfy my needs .I want to generate the 20 div once ready then how to make that 20 div falling continuously from top to bottom consistently. Is it possible to do that in jquery.
http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/
Here is the code

```
  function fallingSnow() {

        var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
        $('#snowZone').prepend(snowflake);
        snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width());
        snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() + 5000);

        snowflake.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
        snowflake.animate({
            top: "500px",
            opacity : "0",

        }, snowSpd, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            fallingSnow();
        });

    }
    var timer = Math.floor(Math.random() +1000);

    window.setInterval(function(){
        fallingSnow();
    }, timer);
```

Much Appreciate your Help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't satisfy my needs" can you elaborate please?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That script has make it unresponsive and auto generating object. I want to do 20 div as static and then i recalled again and again by moving top and bottom

Comment: May be this will help...http://jsfiddle.net/4cZdu/29/

Comment: Thanks for your demo @Nikhil Did you notice that script has unresponsive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want.

I am animating 20 snowflakes, wait until animation finishes **for all of them**, then restart all over again.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/3/)

```
function fallingSnow() {

    var $snowflakes = $(), qt = 20;

    for (var i = 0; i < qt; ++i) {
        var $snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
        $snowflake.css({
            'left': (Math.random() * $('#site').width()) + 'px',
            'top': (- Math.random() * $('#site').height()) + 'px'
        });
        // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
        $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake);
    }
    $('#snowZone').prepend($snowflakes);

    $snowflakes.animate({
        top: "500px",
        opacity : "0",
    }, Math.random() + 5000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        // run again when all 20 snowflakes hit the floor
        if (--qt < 1) {
            fallingSnow();
        }
    });
}
fallingSnow();
```

---

**Update**

This version creates 20 divs only once, and animate them again and again.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/5/)

```
    function fallingSnow() {
        var $snowflakes = $(),
            createSnowflakes = function () {
                var qt = 20;
                for (var i = 0; i < qt; ++i) {
                    var $snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
                    $snowflake.css({
                        'left': (Math.random() * $('#site').width()) + 'px',
                        'top': (- Math.random() * $('#site').height()) + 'px'
                    });
                    // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
                    $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake);
                }
                $('#snowZone').prepend($snowflakes);
            },

            runSnowStorm = function() {
                $snowflakes.each(function() {

                    var singleAnimation = function($flake) {
                        $flake.animate({
                            top: "500px",
                            opacity : "0",
                        }, Math.random() + 5000, function(){
                            // this particular snow flake has finished, restart again
                            $flake.css({
                                'top': (- Math.random() * $('#site').height()) + 'px',
                                'opacity': 1
                            });
                            singleAnimation($flake);
                        });
                    };
                    singleAnimation($(this));
                });
        };

        createSnowflakes();
        runSnowStorm();
    }
    fallingSnow();
```

---

**Update2**

This one that initializes the `left` once the animation is done for each snowflake, looks more natural in my opinion.
Also changed the delay from

```
Math.random() + 5000
```

to

```
Math.random()*-2500 + 5000
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your Response. I saw that fiddle `I am animating 20 snowflakes, wait until animation finishes for all of them` But I need to loop continuously without generating any additional div

Comment: Don't mistaken me let consider the globe has circle and 20 peoples travelling around the world (they were starting from different countries) one guy has starting from us (top of the site) to australia (bottom of site) and returns again to u.s without waiting any more guys who travel across the world.

Comment: Thanks this what i want

Comment: @masterzoran I made a small addition that re-positions the snow flake in a different `left` position

Comment: i more like my attempt : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331938/create-snow-flakes-in-jquery

Comment: @downvoter, do you care to explain the problem? This way I could improve my answer.

Comment: For this one: http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/881/ How can I make it so it only runs 5 times? Btw this is great, +1 from me.

Comment: @Si8 Here http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/883/ it animates all 20 flakes 5 times, which means you will see 100 snow flakes. I just added an `nTimes` variable that is set at the last line with the value 5.

Comment: Thank you. I just decided to run it without any timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.
Your design of function must be this.

```
function snowflake()
{

if($(".snowflakes").length <= 20)
 { 
    generate_random_snowflake();
 }
else
 {
    call_random_snowflake();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, pretty simple i just added a function that triggers jquerysnow() and then calls itself again wit random time

updated code now it will just create 20 snow flakes

```
snowCount = 0;
function snowFlakes(){
    console.log(snowCount);
    if(snowCount > 20){

        return false
    }else{
    var randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 2);
    setTimeout(function(){
        snowCount = snowCount +1;
        jquerysnow();
       snowFlakes();
    },randomTime);
    }
}
function jquerysnow() {


       var snow = $('<div class="snow"></div>');
        $('#snowflakes').prepend(snow);
        snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#snowflakes').width());
        snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 20);

        snow.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
    snow.html('*');
        snow.animate({
            top: "500px",
            opacity : "0",

        }, 2000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            //jquerysnow();
        });



}

snowFlakes()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7LWx/22/

Comment: +1 thanks  it works:) I want to make loop back again Let consider multiple object fall from top to bottom. But Some one object fall quickly and someone lately reach the bottom. But what i am looking is if anyone of the object is reach the bottom then again loop back from top to bottom (is applicable for all object) is possible ?