# Animate Direction using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created the snow flake with responsive script. Everything seems ok nothing problem. But i want to enhance for the direction of flakes like left to right and right to left and top to bottom like that. I tried but I am not sure where i did the mistake.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCcPn/)**

**Javascript:**

```
        var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            var currentTop = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('top'));
            var currentLeft = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('left'));
            jQuery(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed);
      alert(currentLeft);
//
      //alert(movingDirection);
                if (movingDirection === 0) {
                    jQuery(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed);
                } else {
                    // set the snow move to left
                    jQuery(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed));
                }
```

How can i move the flake from left to right and right to left?
Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah javascript snowflakes..reminds me of the 90s ;)

Comment: [HOT] Follow this url - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333422/create-random-falling-object-in-jquery/19333584?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `step` callback function of jquery animate:

```
$(function(){
  var drop = $('.drop').detach();
  function create(){
    var clone = drop
      .clone()
      .appendTo('.container')
      .css('left', Math.random()*$(document).width()-20)
    .html('*')
      .animate(
                {'top': $(document).height()-20},
          {
              duration: Math.random(1000)+8000,
              complete:function(){
                 $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){$(this).remove();}); 
               },
              step:function (currentTop){
                                    var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            var currentTop = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('top'));
            var currentLeft = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('left'));
            jQuery(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed);

                if (movingDirection === 0) {
                    jQuery(this).css('left', currentLeft + fallingSpeed);
                } else {
                    // set the snow move to left
                    jQuery(this).css('left', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed));
                }
              }
          });
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qCcPn/6/)