# How to drag a falling object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I took a look at the snow fall plug-in in jQuery.

I divided my window into two panels per se. One for falling effect the other to collect and move objects around.

I am able to click on one snow flake and set its position to a new point and stop it (from moving). However I want to move it around in the pane. How can I achieve this?

There's another issue. After a flake is repositioned, on each consecutive clicks, the flake seems to do continuous repositioning. The best would be,

### ---------EDIT

1. Fall the snow (done)
2. Drag a falling snow to the other pane (right side). Snow flake should *stop* falling. Should be able to drag it anywhere within right side.
3. Double click to delete any stopped and draggable flakes in other pane (Right side)

---

Here's the current code.

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crgor979/2/)

  ```
  // Snow Falling
  function fallingSnow() {

      var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
      $('#snowZone').prepend(snowflake);
      snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width()/3);
      snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() + 50000);

      snowflake.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
      snowflake.animate({
          top: "700px",
          opacity : "5",

      }, snowSpd, function(){
          $(this).remove();
          fallingSnow();
      })

    //on click, the flake to be stopped, and re-positioned. To be able to drag it.

      $( function() {
        $(snowflake).click( function() {
          $(this).toggleClass("blue-cell");
          var pos = $(this).position().left + 200;
          var s = $(this);
          snowflake.css({'left': pos+'px'});                   
          $(s).stop();                      
          $(s).draggable();             
        });
      });      

   //on double click I want to remove the draggable flake in right side pane
   //              $(s).click(function(){
   //                  $(s).remove();
   //              }); 
  }

  var timer = Math.floor(Math.random() +2000);

  window.setInterval(function(){
      fallingSnow();
  }, timer);
  ```

**Refrences:** [The original code was take from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333422/create-random-falling-object-in-jquery)

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @monkeyinsight certainly I have searched through and have seen the `draggable` of `ui` pluggin. But I can't *connect the dots*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just apply `.draggable()` to your snowflake

http://jsfiddle.net/MzVFA/213/

Comment: @bonCodigo no, line #4 `.draggable()` and included jquery-ui

Comment: Shucks... I already had written the code then and it was a matter of the pluggin. +1 Thanks. Infact no need to change line #4 as long as plug-in is enabled. Well I don't want the already stopped-snow balls to keep moving to right side on each click. So do you think I could use an if-statement to check the `isFunction(stop)`? If the snow-flake is not sopped, it shall move to right, otherwise only draggable.